# User Input Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, terminal

I am trying to make a Bash Script that has 4 choices and prompts the user to select an option. Each option corresponds to a Linux Command operation. Can someone give me a bash example on how could this be implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: Check `help read`

Comment: ... I would suggest `help select` as well

Comment: ...or `man dialog`

Comment: A menu with the options in another file is given in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38200/ksh-styling-text-based-menu-using-stderr/115371#115371

Answer (score 2):

Simple user selection example:

```
#!/bin/bash

do_exit=0

while [[ $do_exit == 0 ]]; do

    echo
    read -s -n1 answer

    case $answer in
        'l' )
            ls -l
            ;;
        'm' )
            free
            ;;
        'd' )
            df
            ;;
        'q' )
            do_exit=1
            ;;
        *)
            echo 'Invalid selection'
            ;;
    esac

done
```