# Is it possible to modify the colors in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to configure Bash so that STDERR can be a different color than STDOUT?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/is-it-possible-to-configure-bash-so-that-stderr-can-be-a-different-color-than-st)

In bash, the only color I know how to modify is the prompt, using `\[` and `\]`. From the `man`:

```
          \[     begin a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt
          \]     end a sequence of non-printing characters
```

Is it possible to go further? I'd like to color the user input in a color and possibly use two different colors for `stdout` and `stderr` text printed on the screen.

My setup:

- bash-4.1.5
- Debian Squeeze
- [Openbox](http://openbox.org/)
- my Samsung laptop at home