# How to tell if output of a command or shell script is stdout or stderr

Tags: io-redirection

Let us say I run a command or shell script, and it gives me output. Without knowing the internals of this command or shell script, how does one determine if is the output was from `stderr` or `stdout`?

For e.g.,

```
$ ls -ld /
drwxrwxr-t  35 root  admin  1258 Dec 11 19:16 /
```

vs

```
ls -ld /test
ls: /test: No such file or directory
```

How do I ascertain that the first command printed to `stdout` and the second to `stderr` (did it?)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Was afraid someone would ask that; none really, mostly curious and hoping to improve my understanding of redirection.

Comment: You could put [`stderred`](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) in your shell environment's `LD_PRELOAD` to get `stdout` and `stderr` in different colours. [Here's a related question in that vein.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/can-i-configure-my-shell-to-print-stderr-and-stdout-in-different-colors)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's no way to tell once the output has already been printed.  In this case, both `stdout` and `stderr` are connected to the terminal, so the information about which stream was written to was already lost by the time the text appeared on your terminal; they were combined by the program before ever making it to the terminal.

What you can do, in a case like the above, would be to run the command with `stdout` and `stderr` redirected to different places and see what happens.  Or run it twice, once with `stdout` redirected to `/dev/null` and once with `stderr` redirected to `/dev/null`, and see which of those cases results in the text showing up.

You can redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` by tacking `>/dev/null` on the end of the command line, and you can redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` by adding `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 22):

You can redirect stdout using `> file`, and redirect stderr using `2> file`. Many modern shells support redirecting to commands, so you can use `sed` to highlight which output comes from which stream:

```
$ ls 2> >(sed 's/^/2: /') > >(sed 's/^/1: /')
1: unity_support_test.0
1: vmwareDnD

$ ls foo 2> >(sed 's/^/2: /') > >(sed 's/^/1: /')
2: ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Very nice! It would be great if one could highlight the lines in colors rather than prefix.

Comment: @dotancohen: One can! Eg, `(echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr" >&2) > >(sed 's/.*/\x1b[32m&\x1b[0m/') 2> >(sed 's/.*/\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m/')`

Comment: Note that if there's mixed output from stdout and stderr, first stdout will be printed, then stderr.

Answer (score 6):

The `annotate-output` script from Debian's [`devscripts`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/devscripts) lets you do this selectively:

```
$ annotate-output ls -ld /test
14:54:22 -: Started ls -ld /test
14:54:22 E: ls: cannot access /test: No such file or directory
14:54:22 -: Finished with exitcode 2
```

The second column indicates stdout and stderr with `O` and `E` respectively.

There are some caveats, the main one being as noted in the other answers: you can't do this after the fact. Neither the shell nor the terminal are aware of how an arbitrary program uses its file descriptors, though the shell is responsible for setting them up initially.

This method uses fifos, writing to a fifo can behave differently than writing to a tty, and writing to two different fifos is definitely different (potential timing/interleaving issues). Also, it's not suitable for interactive use, e.g. `annotate-output bash` is not a great plan, but it's useful for many other purposes. There are many, many examples of scripts and shell functions in answers to related questions about colorising stdin/stdout/stderr, the most robust is [stderrd](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) which uses runtime modification of (most) programs to modify data written to stderr.

This question that Anko links to has good answers on that related theme: colorising the stdout/stderr output:
[Can I configure my shell to print STDERR and STDOUT in different colors?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/can-i-configure-my-shell-to-print-stderr-and-stdout-in-different-colors)

Comment: Note that  it's a `bash` script using `while read` loops and running one `date` command for each line of stdout or stderr, so it going to be a lot  less efficient than the `cmd > >(ts '%T O:') 2> >(ts '%T E:')` equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answers, it is interessant to point to `/proc/$PID/fd` (although it does not answer the question):

```
$ cat > /dev/null 2> /tmp/blablah &
[1] 3073

[1]+  Stopped                 cat > /dev/null 2> /tmp/blablah
$ ls -l /proc/3073/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 kampde kampde 64 Feb 24 11:43 0 -> /dev/pts/33
l-wx------ 1 kampde kampde 64 Feb 24 11:43 1 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 kampde kampde 64 Feb 24 11:43 2 -> /tmp/blablah
```

As you see, here you can see the file descriptors opened for a process. `0` is the `STDIN`, `1` is the `STDOUT` and `2` is the `STDERR`. If you didn't have the STDOUT or STDERR redirected, you'd see `/dev/pts/33` (in this example at least) because they would point to the terminal.

*notes*: `/proc/$PID` only exists for running processes. In this case I have used `cat` without arguments so it does not end until I close the `STDIN`. I have also executed it in the background so I have the PID immediately for the sake of this example.

Answer (score 1):

Usually STDERR will have the program name prepended to the message with a colon.

Example:

```
rpm -zq some_utils 
rpm: -zq: unknown option
```

Vs

```
rpm -ql some_utils 
package some_utils is not installed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of grep for this very easily:

```
$ ls -l test | grep .
ls: cannot access 'test': No such file or directory
```

This assumes that your grep output is coloured (this is the default on most distros).

This will result in `stdout` being highlighted with the default grep colour, for example:

```
$ (echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr" >&2) | grep .
this is stderr
this is stdout
```

The first line of output is white while the second is coloured. This might be the opposite of what you want if your default grep colour is red. If you explicitly want to set `stdout` to green you could do this to set the grep colours to green:

```
$ GREP_COLORS='ms=01;32'
$ (echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr" >&2) | grep .
```

If you explicitly want to get red output for `stderr`:

```
$ GREP_COLORS='ms=01;31'
$ (echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr" >&2) 2> >(grep .)
```

If you really want both stderr and stdout to be specific colours then you can do this:

```
$ (echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr" >&2) 2> >(GREP_COLORS='ms=01;31' grep .) 1> >(GREP_COLORS='ms=01;32' grep .)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you are asking but this might help

```
ls -ld /
echo $?    # Exit status 0 returned because command executed successfully.

ls -ld /test
echo $?    # Non-zero exit status returned -- command failed to execute
```

[Source](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)

If exit code is 0 it simply means that command is executed correctly (stdout), [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) you can find meanings if exit code is different than 0 (stderr)

Comment: Very interesting! I would've never connected exit statuses with redirection. Does zero imply `stdout` and non-zero imply `stderr`?

Comment: @KM., no.  I'd say it strongly correlates, but there's nothing that stops a program from writing to `stderr` and returning a good error code, or writing to `stdout` and returning a bad error code.  In fact, try `find /root` - assuming you're not running as root, you should get 2 lines printed out - "/root" gets printed to `stdout`, and "find: /root: Permission denied" gets printed to `stderr`.  And find returns a bad return code.

Comment: op's problem is clear that how to tell which is stdout or stderr.

Answer (score -1):

To capture and test for error output:

```
ls -l test 2>errors
if [ -s errors ]; then echo "There were errors:" && cat errors; fi
rm errors
```