# How can I convert to uppercase stderr output but not stdout?

Tags: stdout, stderr

I'm using rsync to backup some files:

```
rsync -PaSh --stats --delete -e "-i key -p XXXX" "/source/" username@192.168.0.1:/destination/ 2> output.txt | grep -e 'bytes  received' -e 'total bytes' -e files -e 'total file size:' >> output.txt
```

because there are thousands of files, I only want to see any errors and a summary at the end.

The above command outputs this:

```
rsync: delete_file: unlink(test/test.txt) failed: Permission denied (13)
Number of files: 12 (reg: 10, dir: 2)
Number of created files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
sent 382 bytes  received 137 bytes  41.52 bytes/sec
```

I want to convert to uppercase any errors only (to draw attention to them) and leave the summary unchanged.

So it would look like this:

```
RSYNC: DELETE_FILE: UNLINK(TEST/TEST.TXT) FAILED: PERMISSION DENIED (13)
Number of files: 12 (reg: 10, dir: 2)
Number of created files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
sent 382 bytes  received 137 bytes  41.52 bytes/sec
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Side comment/question not mentioned in my answer: wouldn't it be easier to just `tail` the `rsync` _stdout_ to get the summary info? Or does it get displayed elsewhere besides the very end of the `rsync` run? (If it would work that's a lot better than scanning the whole thing with `grep`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can effectively swap *stdin* and *stdout* with the help of a temporary file descriptor (fd 3 here):

```
cmd 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3- | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper]'
```

That says "point new fd at the place *stderr* points to, point *stderr* where *stdout* points, point *stdout* to where *stderr* originally pointed"...easy, right? :)

Or in other words: now the *stderr* from `cmd` will go through the pipe like *stdout* while the original *stdout* has been redirected to *stderr*. And the `tr` command will do the upper-case conversion.

**Update:** Though you accepted the answer above your wishlist included the ability to manipulate *stdout* and *stderr* simultaneously. So let's try to tackle that...keeping in mind that we're bumping up against some things I don't do too often!

A simple swapping of *stdout*/*stderr* won't do anything useful. With or without the swap you can't use two different streams through a single pipeline. The first thing that comes to mind as an alternative is to use FIFOs (named pipes):

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo1 /tmp/fifo2

# run the key command in the background, in a subshell to suppress
# job control messages (e.g. "[1] 12345" and "[1]+ Exit ...")
( cmd > /tmp/fifo1 2> /tmp/fifo2 & )

# concatenate tr/stderr and grep/stdout using process substitution
# (I'm assuming the summary information occurs at the end of rsync output)
cat <(cat /tmp/fifo2 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') <(grep ... /tmp/fifo1) 

rm -f /tmp/fifo1 /tmp/fifo2
```

You could actually put this all on one line if so inclined!

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo1 /tmp/fifo2; (cmd > /tmp/fifo1 2> /tmp/fifo2 &); cat <(cat /tmp/fifo2 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') <(grep ... /tmp/fifo1); rm -f /tmp/fifo1 /tmp/fifo2
```

My sanity checks are working okay so give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I'm getting closer. I'm now using this:  `rsync -PaSh --stats --delete -e "-i key -p XXXX" "/source/" username@192.168.0.1:/destination/ 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] > output.txt | grep -e 'bytes  received' -e 'total bytes' -e files -e 'total file size:' >> output.txt` which works in converting stderr to uppercase. Unfortunately I lose the ability to append stdout to the file and instead it just appears on screen. Do I need to add `1>` somewhere?

Comment: @NoExpert You want to save to file the original stdout straight from the `rsync` command, yes?

Comment: Only one stream can go through those pipes. You can't have both the `tr` for the stderr and `grep` for the stdout in a single command.

Comment: Yes, after greping what I need, so as in my example in the original above. Thank you.

EDIT: OK I've seen your updated answer now. That makes sense. I guess I'll have to live with it.

Comment: I think you can accomplish what you want if you're willing to use named pipes (FIFOs). I'll post an update to my answer.

Comment: That fifo approach [is prone to deadlocks](/a/66875)

Answer (score 1):

To convert stderr to uppercase without changing where stdout and stderr go to:

```
{ rsync ... 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | perl -Mopen=locale -pe '$_=uc' >&2 3>&-; } 3>&1
```

That is duplicate the original stdout onto fd 3, so we can restore it for `rsync`.

Here using `perl` instead of `tr` as it gives better results for things like `Stéphane` -> `STÉPHANE` (`STéPHANE` with GNU `tr`) or `traﬃc` -> `TRAFFIC` (`TRAﬃC` with GNU tr/sed/awk).

Note that now that stderr goes through a pipe, that can affect the relative order of stdout and stderr messages as the stderr messages are now being delayed.

See

- [Can I configure my shell to print STDERR and STDOUT in different colors?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12439)

for some other approaches that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command instead of your command. I have added one extra command after redirecting the error to output.txt

I have added sed -i "s/.*/\U&/g"  output.txt
As tested its works fine

---

```
rsync -PaSh --stats --delete -e "-i key -p XXXX" "/source/" username@192.168.0.1:/destination/ 2> output.txt ;sed -i  "s/.*/\U&/g" output.txt| grep -e 'bytes  received' -e 'total bytes' -e files -e 'total file size:' >> output.txt
```

---