# Send stderr to a different receiver in pipe

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdout, stderr, tee

Right now I have this:

```
 echo "$run_test" | bash 2>&1 | prepend "r2g-test:" "yellow";
```

What this does is prepend "r2g-test:" to each line of the stdout/stderr.
Because I am sending stderr to stdout, the `prepend` program doesn't know the difference because it's all stdin to it.

Is there some way I can send stderr to a different `prepend` instance, perhaps with `tee`?

Perhaps something like this?

```
 echo "$run_test" | bash 2> $(prepend 'r2g-test:' 'red') | prepend 'r2g-test:' 'yellow';
```

This might work, with process substitution:

```
bash 2> >(prepend 'r2g-test:' 'red')
```

But so far, the stderr never shows up in the terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I configure my shell to print STDERR and STDOUT in different colors?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/can-i-configure-my-shell-to-print-stderr-and-stdout-in-different-colors)

Comment: Nah this one is more specifically about pipelines, that is more general

Comment: No worries. I looked at what you seemed to be trying to achieve rather then the mechanics of one possible solution

Comment: Yeah this is pretty tricky stuff np

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's create a program `run_test` which generates both stdout and stderr:

```
$ run_test() { while sleep 0.2; do echo "Out $((++c))"; echo "err$c">&2; done; }
```

Now, let's send the stdout and stderr to different filters.  Since I don't have a `prepend` installed, I will use `sed` for the same purpose:

```
$ exec 3>&2; { run_test | sed 's/^/stdout: /'; } 2>&1 1>&3 | sed 's/^/stderr: /'
stdout: Out 1
stderr: err1
stdout: Out 2
stderr: err2
stdout: Out 3
stderr: err3
```

#### How it works

- `exec 3>&2`

  This creates file descriptor 3 as a duplicate of stderr.
- `run_test | sed 's/^/stdout: /'`

  This runs `run_test` and prepends `stdout:` to the beginning of stdout.
- `{ run_test | sed 's/^/stdout: /'; } 2>&1 1>&3`

  `2>&` redirects stderr to stdout so that stderr will go into the next pipe.  `1>&3` redirects stdout to stderr so that it appears on the terminal.
- `{ run_test | sed 's/^/stdout: /'; } 2>&1 1>&3 | sed 's/^/stderr: /'`

  The last pipe captures run_test's stderr, (which is now stdout) and prepends `stderr:` to it.

#### Using process substitution

```
$ run_test > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /') 2> >(stdbuf -oL sed 's/^/stderr: /' >&2)
stdout: Out 1
stderr: err1
stdout: Out 2
stderr: err2
stdout: Out 3
stderr: err3
```

The above uses `stdbuf` which is standard on Linux.  For other OS's, one will need to look for analogous commands.

Comment: thanks! There must be a simpler way! I saw something like this using an intermediate fd, but I hoping for something less xrazy. What about this: `echo "$run_test" | bash 2> >(prepend 'r2g-test:' 'red') | prepend 'r2g-test:' 'yellow';` ... why won't that work?

Comment: that uses process substitution, but the stderr never seems to show up in the terminal

Comment: @AlexanderMills I added a solution using process substitution.  Note that anytime one one separates the two streams, output order is not guaranteed.

Comment: thanks, I asked a new question, because this one was a bit unclear: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442250/stderr-is-being-sent-down-pipeline-but-i-dont-want-that

Comment: nice `sed` prepending trick by the way, i didn't know that you could do that

Comment: I guess I don't understand what this is for:

Comment: `run_test > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /') 2> >(stdbuf -oL sed 's/^/stderr: /' >&2)`

Comment: what is `>&2` for in the above command?

Comment: `>&2` sends stdout to stderr for that process.  Without that, the stderr gets captured again by stdout resulting in lines like `stdout: stderr: err1`.

Comment: Got it thanks. Using your first technique with `exec 3>&2`, looks like stderr and stdout are not ordered. Is there some way to force them to always appear in the order in which they were produced? They are produced by the same bash process, so nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: this is what I have for context: `exec 3>&2; {  echo "$run_test" | bash | prepend 'r2g-test: ' 'yellow'; } 2>&1 1>&3 | prepend 'r2g-test: ' 'red'`

Comment: the stderr is appearing first, when it should be appearing second in my case

Comment: Anytime that the two streams are separated, output order is not guaranteed.  It depends on buffering for which `stdbuf -oL` might help.  Also, there are three processes running: bash and the two prepends.  The final output order also depends on which `prepend` happens, under the vagaries of multitasking, to get more CPU time than the other.

Comment: well what if you could separate them and then reconnect them? would that help to guarantee a little more order than o/w? prolly right