# stderr is being sent down pipeline but I don't want that

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, stdout, stderr

I have this:

```
    echo "$some_command" | bash 2> >(prepend 'r2g-stderr:' 'red') | prepend 'r2g-stdout:' 'yellow';
```

What I am trying to do:

```
r2g-stderr: this is some stderr
r2g-stderr: this is some more stderr
r2g-stderr: this is some mo mo stderr
r2g-stdout: this is some stdout
r2g-stdout: this more stdout
```

and of course, the r2g-stderr / r2g-stdout will have different colors.

the problem is I am getting output that looks like this:

```
r2g-stdout: r2g-stderr: this is some stderr
r2g-stdout: r2g-stderr: this is some more stderr
r2g-stdout: r2g-stderr: this is some mo mo stderr
r2g-stdout: this is some stdout
r2g-stdout: this more stdout
```

I think it's because the stderr from the process substitution is somehow making it's way to the second prepend command, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does `prepend` print its output? To `stderr` or to `stdout`? I think the process substitution in `cmd 2> >(procsub) | ...` inherits the redirection of *`stdout`* set by the pipe.

You'd need to do something like this to explicitly redirect the output from the process substitution command to `stderr` again:

```
cmd 2> >(procsub >&2) | pipecmd
```

or replace the pipe with another process substitution:

```
cmd 2> >(procsub) 1> >(pipecmd)
```

The latter looks cleaner to me, but in this case all of the resulting output goes to `stdout` (of the outside environment), and at least my Bash returns to the prompt before the process substitutions finish, so the output gets intermixed with the prompt.

The first one works though:

```
$ bash someoutput.sh  2> >(sed -e 's/^/ERR:/' >&2)  | sed -e 's/^/OUT:/'
ERR:error message
OUT:normal output
```

But remember that after the redirections, the original order of the error output and normal output may not remain at the end. My script above actually printed the `normal output` string first, but sometimes the error line shows up first, as above.

Comment: yeah `prepend` always prints to `stdout`

Comment: perhaps that is the issue, not sure

Comment: @AlexanderMills, that's to be expected: it can't know if its input originally came from an error stream or a regular output stream. And then it probably saves its own stderr for its own errors, as usual..