# Interactive bash script: Prefix all lines with a string

Tags: bash, scripting, io-redirection, command-history, interactive

I want to create an interactive CLI in bash. Similar to the way bash prefixes every line with `user@host:~$`, I would like to prefix every line with `foobar>`. This functionality can be seen in CLI applications like Metasploit or mysqli, but they use separate programming languages whereas I would like to simply use bash scripting. Additionally, I need the up/down arrow keys to use the `history` functionality (or something similar), allowing the user to easily bring up the last input or the nth previous to that.

In trying to create a solution, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5003870) which allows the arrow keys to be interpreted by bash and bring up the last input using `history`. This works well, however I am having a hard time combining this with line prefixing. I found a solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157695) to use coproc to preprocess stdout and implemented a version of this, however, this method neither works for the input line you are typing on, nor the lines pulled up using the arrow keys with `history`. The bash script I have so far is below:

```
exec 4>&1
coproc out (sed 's/^/foobar> /' >&4)
exec 1>&${out[1]}

printf "foobar> " >&4
while read -e x; do
   history -s "$x"
   echo $x
done
```

Here is the output which details both problems. As you can see below, I am able to prefix the very first line of the cli by using `printf "foobar> " >&4` in my above script before the while loop. Below I type `boop` on this first line, and the output from echo is redirected to my coproc. However after this, using the up arrow to bring the input `boop` back will print `boop` without my prefix (as seen on the last line).

```
$ ./test.sh
foobar> boop
foobar> boop
boop
```

I do realize that because I don't have a printf inside the loop, the line I am typing on isn't going to be prefixed after the first iteration. I can fix this later by reworking the loop (though I am worried about sending the prefix line to the prefixing coproc, thus double prefixing). What I mainly need to fix is the up arrow output **not** getting prefixed. I was under the assumption this information was sent via `stdout`, but apparently it isn't. I've tried redirecting `stderr` in the same manner as well but that stops the terminal from echoing what I type as I type it.

I need a solution for prefixing each line in a bash script, whether it builds off the script I have provided above or uses a different method. I would also like it to be as elegant as possible, as I am going to be building a CLI tool using this technique and would prefer as little extra overhead as possible. I thought redirection would do this for me but apparently it's more complicated than I first thought.

Comment: The PS should be a separate question.

Comment: You're correct, it should. I will make one if it doesn't exist already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really following this `coproc` thing. In your case `read -p` seems just right. And you may want to use a separate (non-default) history file.

Warning: the script creates/uses `$HOME/.custom_history` to save its history. After you test the solution, remove the file by hand.

```
#!/bin/bash

# History management
hfile="$HOME/.custom_history"
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
history -r "$hfile"
trap 'history -a "$hfile"' exit

# Main loop
while read -ep 'foobar> ' x; do
   history -s -- "$x"
   printf '%s\n' "$x"
done
```

<sup>Basic idea borrowed from [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1418665/432690).</sup>